# Cordova.js linked, deviceready not firing

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

I've linked cordova.js, I have `app.initialize();`, and deviceready does not fire. Anyone know why?

JS:

```
var app = {
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
        document.getElementById("finishbutton").addeventlistener("click", greet)
    },
    function greet(){
        alert("The button works.")
    }

};

app.initialize();
```

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="app">
            <h1>Apache Cordova</h1>
            <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
                <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
                <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button id = "finishbutton">Finish</button>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        app.initialize();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

If deviceready fires, I should be able to push the finish button and get my alert. Instead, it just locks up on "CONNECTING TO DEVICE".

Comment: You forgot two ";". Behind "getElementById" and "alert" lines.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  var app = {
        initialize: function() {
            this.bindEvents();
        },
        bindEvents: function() {
            document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
        },
        onDeviceReady: function() {
            app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
            document.getElementById("finishbutton").addEventListener("click", this.greet); 
    /*here you were missing the ";" and "Event" and "Listener" should be 
capitalized */
            },
            greet: function(){
              alert("The button works."); /*here you were missing the ";", too. additionally i think you should use greet: function() */
            }

        };
```